# How to install unavailable python packages in aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I gonna install pyaudio and sounddevice packages via requirements.txt in EC2.
But it says `raise OSError('PortAudio library not found')`
So I tried to install libasound-dev for sounddevice...

```
Yum install libasound-dev
```

But it also said :

```
No package libasound-dev available
```

How should I do? I am in AWS EC2.

Comment: what instance? You haven't provided any information what operating system are you using, its version.

Comment: It is Amazon Linux 2/3.3.5   I deployed the Django2.2.22

Comment: @Marcin do you know how to debug the running Django applicatoin in  aws ec2?

Comment: I would suggest making new question with details of what you want to achieve and any errors you get.

Comment: I posted new question @Marcin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libasound-dev` is for Ubuntu. For `Amazon Linux 2` it should be:

```
sudo yum install alsa-lib-devel
```

For portaudio:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install -y portaudio-devel portaudio
```

Comment: I did run it, actually what I want is to install Sounddevice package for python, but it still says "PortAudio library not found". how should I do to install the sounddevice?

Comment: @MaSao93 I updated the answer but if you have other errors, please make new question for that. Also acceptance of my answer would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for your support, it worked well, I will appreciated a lot, Have you experienced in aws polly sdk?

Comment: @MaSao93 No problem. Sadly I haven't worked with aws polly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Window and gonna use pyaudio, you would use like this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

This works well on Window.